# ATG Commerce weblogic clustering

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, atg

I am trying to setup a weblogic cluster running ATG Commerce. I have installed weblogic on machine A, with the following configuration.

Weblogic admin server

Managed servers: Production_A, Production_B, Publishing_A and Publishing_B that

shall run on machine A and B accordingly.

***Do I have to install weblogic on machine B also?***

(While installation of ATG commerce it ask which is our application server. I mean to say the production and publishing server shall run inside the weblogic  server of machine A).
Secondly, do I have to actually specify the managed servers in weblogic while installing it on machine A. I mean to say while installing ATG commerce in machine B, during CIM configuration, I specify the weblogic of machine A, and I create production_B and publishing_B to run inside A's weblogic.
I am confused wheater I'm doing it right.

The managed servers production_B and publishing_B appear in A's weblogic After I do CIM configuration on B. The I set up machines(A and B in A's weblogic), add servers to machines, Add servers to cluster. Everything is happening. But when I try to run B's servers from A's weblogic, the servers do not start saying nodemanager is unreachable. In machine A, I have set the node manager for machine B to Machine A(I need to ask like will the node manager for machine B's server? Or it will run in A's weblogic node manager(production_A and Publishing_A runs with this node manager)) machine A is reachable from machine B(I can open weblogic console of Machine A on Machine B). Am I missing on anything?

Can Anyone direct me to a reference/blog for weblogic clustering in ATG Commerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to install WebLogic on every physical machine on which you intend to deploy your EAR. It is the servlet container that you'll be using so without it (and it's obvious dependencies like JAVA) you won't be able to run your deployments on that machine.

As far as your ATG instances are concerned, I would do it as follow:

Create Commerce A and Publishing A on Server A (using CIM). Something that you are missing though is you have no LockManager configured. You'll require at least one of these to maintain your locks across your Commerce Instances and possibly another to do the same across your publishing instances (I've never deployed a clustered publishing environment, only ever one BCC per environment).

Having done the configuration on Server A, manually copy the ATG-Data/servers folder (or /servers) folder from Server A to Server B. Because you don't install ATG on every machine, in fact you don't need ATG to be deployed if you create your EAR in standalone mode, I would recommend you setup an ATG-Data folder on both Server A and Server B and deploy your configs in there.

Now, having copied the servers folder you will need to manually edit the following files:
Configuration.properties

- This probably contains references to Server A that you want to update.
- The Ports on Server B can be the same (per instance) as it is on Server A
- Update the otherLockServer property in the LockManager instance (if you created it) for both Server A and Server B to reference the 'other lock server'
- Update the ClientLockManager to point at both LockManagers

From a WebLogic point of view you need to create the servers on each instance as well. Even within a WebLogic Cluster (which is licensed separately with Oracle and not included in your ATG License) you need an AdminServer per WebLogic. I believe the NodeManager configuration would be different but I've not set this up in a WebLogic cluster, yet.

Comment: Sir I successfully configured the cluster as you told..:D Thanks a lot!!